# Executing all shell scripts inside a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory structure like the following -

```
/Apple/A/B/test.sh
/Apple/D/test.sh
/Apple/G/F/H/test.sh
```

Basically, there is the folder Apple and there exists shell scripts in its subdirectories.

It might not necessarily have a shell script in each of its subdirectory.

How can I run all scripts there are in the Apple folder without manually having to go to each sub-folder and executing it?

Answer (score 7):

```
find Apple/ -name "*.sh" -exec {} \;
```

Comment: Just a note for OP: do check the working directory in which you want to run these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
for script in $(find Apple/ -name '*.sh'); do
  $script; # or sh $script if they are not executable
done
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls` or `find` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)... `find -exec` is much safer option.

Comment: Nice, I hadn't considered that.